# background images are not working in ie8?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am appying the images in table sorter like this.

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp:not(.nosort) {
    background-image: url('/sorter/asc.gif'); 
}
```

In all browsers are images are working but ie8 and ie7 not working this,the images are not visible in ie8.please let me know how to acheive this?

Thanks,
EDIT :

```
 table.tablesorter {
        font-family:arial;
        color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
        margin:10px 0pt 15px;
        font-size: 10pt;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
     }
    table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
        background-color: #8dbdd8;
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        font-size: 10pt;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    table.tablesorter thead tr .header.nosort {
        background-image: url('/sorter/bg.gif');  
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center right;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table.tablesorter tbody td {
            background-color: rgb(239, 243, 251);
            padding: 5px;
            border: solid 1px #e8eef4;

        vertical-align: top;
    }
    table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
        background-color:#F0F0F6;
    }
    table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp.nosort {
        background-image: url('/sorter/asc.gif'); 
    }
    table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown.nosort {
        background-image: url('/sorter/desc.gif'); 
    }
    table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
    background-color: #8dbdd8;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the complimentary markup for these styles? Perhaps a demo on jsfiddle as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support `:not()` selectors. It's very likely this is the cause of your issue. If you're trying to target all `.headerSortUp` that are *not* also `.nosort` you should instead make this your default `.headerSortUp` style, and add special overrides for those that are also `.nosort`:

```
table.tablesorter .headerSortUp {
    // This background is removed when .nosort is present
    background-image: url('/sorter/asc.gif'); 
}

table.tablesorter .headerSortUp.nosort {
    background-image: none; 
}
```

Comment: please check my above edit code.same like as you said i applied but i am loading images in any browser.